# Phonegap Plugin Shutdown

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build

Can someone please explain to me what Phonegap means by it's deleting its plugin repository and "Please be sure to update these apps to use plugins from npmjs.com or git repositories before November 15th, 2016, as after this time those apps will not be built." Does this mean that plugins I manually installed from github won't work past November 15? Here is the link to what I'm talking about: http://phonegap.com/blog/2016/10/13/pgb-repository-shutting-down/

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning, Phonegap Build only allowed to use the plugins they knew that were compatible with their platform, and hosted them on their own repository.
Over time, they have improved their product making it compatible with more plugins and allowing to use another sources such us github or npm, so there is no point of keeping their repository as most plugins there, are outdated or have the same code of the official plugins.

So, if you are using github plugins you are good to go, if you are using npm plugins you are good too.

Make sure you don't have any `gap:plugin` tag in your config.xml and double check all the plugins that use . on the id, as core plugins moved to - syntax (example, it was org.apache.cordova.device and now cordova-plugin-device)